# Keeping a COM object alive to queue longrunning tasks

Tags: c#, com

From what I understand, COM objects can only be used in the thread they were instantiated in. If that thread dies, the object becomes invalid and you can't use it anymore. The error I face when I attempt to is `COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.` The advice I've typically seen to deal with this is just to reinitialize a new COM object for every task you want to run.

The problem is that the COM object I'm using handles communication with another program, and re-establishing the connection with the same instance of that program with a new COM object is tricky. The operations I want to run are long winded and require feedback from the user in between, so including all the operations in a single Task is not really feasible afaik.

What I want to do is build a wrapper around that COM object that puts calls to it into a queue to be invoked by the appropriate thread, that would be compatible with async/await, and I would like to know if that's possible. But to avoid the XY problem I'll ask something different:

What is the most elegant way to keep a COM object functioning, off the main thread, so that I can continue to use it for multiple things?

Comment: That's a serious bug in the code.  Fix the bug.

Comment: "COM objects can only be used in the thread they were instantiated" is not true in the general case. It depends on how the COM object declares it behaves (STA/MTA). "If that thread dies, the object becomes invalid" is only true for STA-marked COM object (the MTA thread never dies). Indeed if your COM object is STA and must live forever, just make sure the thread it was created on lives forever. Or build a MTA-compatible COM object. Lots of misconceptions here. You should show some reproducing code, your question is very vague and your ideas to solve your problem far off the ground.

Comment: Like Simon said, it is not true that COM objects can only be used in the thread they were created in. One purpose of COM marshaling is to be able to use COM objects across threads. Think about the famous use case...someone writes VB to control something in Excel, Word, or Outlook. They start with `set word = CreateObject("Word.Application")`. That object is created in another thread which is in another whole process.

Comment: yes, I may have misspoke, COM objects handle their own marshalling and can be used across threads, but only if the thread they live in exists. Which means instantiating it in a task to go in a random thread from the thread pool to then immediately die simply isn't useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.

To keep the COM object alive you need to declare a corresponding RCW at a global scope, so the reference counter is not declared when the RCW is swiped from the heap. Also you need to pay attention to any [Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject?view=net-6.0) calls that may lead to the issue you faced with. This method is used to explicitly control the lifetime of a COM object used from managed code. You should use this method to free the underlying COM object that holds references to resources in a timely manner or when objects must be freed in a specific order.

For example, if you deal with Office applications like Outlook, it may detect cross-thread calls and throw exceptions in such cases.

The best solution is create a scheduler which can be called from secondary threads and queue such calls on the main thread to communicate with a COM server. Or just consider extracting all the required information (scalar value that don't involve COM objects) which can be simply consumed from secondary threads and then process it in the way you need.

Comment: this combined with Simon's comment confirming "...if your COM object is STA and must live forever, just make sure the thread it was created on lives forever." is what I was looking for, thank you